# Web-CAT CxxTest Eclipse GUI for test results not showing up

Tags: c++, unit-testing, eclipse-cdt, cxxtest

I am trying to execute test cases using CxxTest framework on Eclipse. After following instructions on this website - http://web-cat.cs.vt.edu/eclipse/cxxtest/

I am able to build the test case, but when I run it, it doesn't show the GUI (green/red bar) as shown in the article. I checked CxxTest guide, it mentioned about this flag "--gui=Win32Gui"; can someone help me where can I enter this flag in Eclipse settings? I am using Eclipse CDT (3.6.2) with Web-CAT plug in for CxxTest. I have cygwin installed with make, gcc, g++, gdb.

Here is the output of build:

Building target: BankAccountTests.exe
Invoking: Cygwin C++ Linker
g++  -o"BankAccountTests.exe"  ./BankAccount.o ./runAllTests.o   -lbfd -lz -lintl -liberty
Finished building target: BankAccountTests.exe

Comment: I found the solution to seeing GUI results by adding a view tab using IN ECLIPSE Window-> Show view -> Other -> CxxTest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to seeing GUI results by adding a view tab using IN ECLIPSE Window-> Show view -> Other -> CxxTest.